# How to remove a property for each object in an array?

Tags: javascript

Let say I have

```
let a = [{
  foo: 1
  bar: 1
  baz: 1
},{
  foo: 2
  bar: 2
  baz: 2
},{
  foo: 3
  bar: 3,
  baz: 3
}];
```

How can I remove `bar` in every object so I get

```
a = [{ foo: 1, baz: 1 }, { foo: 2, baz: 2 }, { foo: 3, baz: 3 }];
```

I simplified the example but each object can have many properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.map` to transform each element of an array into another. Also note that your snippet's syntax is invalid; properties of an object need to be separated with a comma.

```js
const input = [{
  foo: 1,
  bar: 1
},{
  foo: 2,
  bar: 2
},{
  foo: 3,
  bar: 3
}];
const output = input.map(({ foo }) => ({ foo }));
console.log(output);
```

If you want to remove one property rather than save some particular properties, you can do something similar using object rest/spread:

```js
const input = [{
  foo: 1,
  bar: 1,
  baz: 1
},{
  foo: 2,
  bar: 2,
  baz: 2
},{
  foo: 3,
  bar: 3,
  baz: 3
}];
const output = input.map(({ foo, ...otherProps }) => ({ ...otherProps }));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks but I need an opt-out solution, that's why I wrote *each object can have many properties.*

Comment: beautiful solution

Answer (score 1):

use `Object.assign` so you don't loose the first object and create a new one with the desired properties :

```js
const a = [{
  foo: 1,
  bar: 1,
  baz: 1
},{
  foo: 2,
  bar: 2,
  baz: 2
},{
  foo: 3,
  bar: 3,
  baz: 3
}];

const b = Object.assign(a.map(({foo, baz}) => ({foo, baz}) ), {});

console.log( JSON.stringify(b) )

console.log(a)
```